# Why is Xcode starting on macOS Sierra start up?

Tags: macos, xcode

After starting or restarting macOS, Xcode is launching and opening a file that I never touched. Any idea how I can stop that?
[image: Xcode]

Comment: Can you translate that info into English?  English language is the default for this site and it will reach the largest possible audience to help with your issue.  Also, please don't use screenshots of the error, paste the error so we can read it all.  See [ask] for tips on asking questions. - From Review.

Comment: Check in System Preferences -  Users & Groups, Login Items tab. Perhaps the document or Xcode is listed there.

Comment: @Scot Thank you, that did it! I have no idea how it got in there, but removing it fixed the problem :) Why didn't you make it an answer to that I can give you the credit for it? ;-)

Comment: @fsb What are you looking to be translated? This is a binary plist .strings file being read with Xcode's plain text editor. It's not an error and the text doesn't need to be in the question since that's not the purpose of this question. It'd be wrong to open this with a plist editor and add that to the question since that's not what the user is seeing when they turn their computer on per the rest of the question.

Comment: @grgarside I see that the file is named MainMenu.strings.  I know that .strings file are readable and can be named whatever you want.  Without context in the question, it looked to me like it just wasn't written in english.  I thought the error being asked about was within that file in the red text.hence the question.

Comment: @bandanh It was a possibility, so I thought it more fitting as a comment. I have since made it an answer. Glad it solved the issue for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that either the `MainMenu.strings` file (or Xcode itself) is listed as a Login Item.

Check this in System Preferences - Users & Groups, Login Items tab and remove the file.